# How do I dynamically scale elements in a specific Javascript that only uses pixels?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, scale, css-position

I am trying to use the jQuery plugin: Floating boxes with easing and motion-blur in jQuery By: Marcell Jusztin.

I have it working just fine and understand how to tweak most attributes, but I am a Javascript rookie and really do not understand the mechanics involved in changing how it uses math to place the elements I want to animate. What I want to do is change the set x and y offset coordinates (which are in pixels of course) to a set of percentages so that the elements will dynamically scale in position based on screen resolution. Here is the script in its entirety:

```
jQuery.fn.floatingBox = function ( userOptions ) {

options = jQuery.extend ({
    parent    : 'backdrop',
    stage     : 'backdrop',
    scale     : 0.3,
    xOffset   : 0,
    yOffset   : 0,
    blur      : false,
    isText    : false,
    blurColor : '#888',
    frameRate : 40,
}, userOptions);


var parent = options.parent;
var stage = options.stage;
var scale = options.scale;
var xOffset = options.xOffset;
var yOffset = options.yOffset;
var blur = options.blur;
var isText = options.isText;
var blurColor = options.blurColor;
var frameRate = options.frameRate;

var midX = $('#' + stage).width() / 2;
var midY = $('#' + stage).height() / 2;
var _x = midX;
var _y = midY;
var xx = midX;
var yy = midY;

var objectId = $(this).attr('id');
$('#' + objectId).css('position','absolute');

shadowAmount = 0;

window["timer" + objectId] = window.setInterval(update,frameRate);


$('#' + parent).mousemove(function(event){

    _x = event.pageX; 
    _y = event.pageY;

    if( shadowAmount < 5 && blur == true ) shadowAmount += scale;

});

factor = scale * 0.5;   

function update() {

        xx += (((_x - midX) * -scale) - xx) * factor;
        yy += (((_y - midY) * -scale) - yy) * factor;
        $('#' + objectId).css('left', xx + xOffset + $('#' + parent).position().left);
        $('#' + objectId).css('top', yy + yOffset + $('#' + parent).position().top);
        if(blur){
            if(!isText){
                $('#' + objectId).css('box-shadow', '0px 0px ' + shadowAmount + 'px ' + blurColor );
                $('#' + objectId).css('-moz-box-shadow', '0px 0px ' + shadowAmount + 'px ' + blurColor );
                $('#' + objectId).css('-webkit-box-shadow', '0px 0px ' + shadowAmount + 'px ' + blurColor );
                $('#' + objectId).css('-o-box-shadow', '0px 0px ' + shadowAmount + 'px ' + blurColor );
            }else{
                $('#' + objectId).css('text-shadow', '0px 0px ' + shadowAmount + 'px ' + blurColor );
            }
            if(shadowAmount > 0 ) shadowAmount -= scale;
        }


}
```

}

Here is the script that initiates the javascript in the HTML document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function(){

        $('#biglogo').floatingBox({ 
            scale : 0.09,
            blur : false,
            isText : false,
            xOffset : 400,
            yOffset: 200,
        });

            $('#biglogo2').floatingBox({    
            scale : 0.08,
            blur : false,
            isText : false,
            xOffset : 405,
            yOffset: 205,
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have two transparent png files that are layered over each other with a minor offset of 5 pixels (or maybe its considered 10), but would rather the two images be centered in all browser windows and not just mine. The scale indicates how fast and far the elements move. The xOffset and yOffset parameters are of course fixed numbers that don't scale based on browser window size.

I have attempted to research this but ultimately, I'm neither finding that it can't be done, nor that it can because no one response seems to address the specific issue I am having. Perhaps I am not wording it correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: if you're talking about merely position the image in the viewport center - you can use the `background-position` CSS attribute set to `50% 50%`.

Comment: @Eliran Malka - The javascript plugin negates any css positioning and uses it's own through the xOffset and yOffset parameters. I have CSS positioning for the elements should javascript be disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of the script I would say that it already takes the necessary calculations into accout. Try setting the `parent` and `stage` options and leave out the offset parameters. I.e

```
$('#biglogo').floatingBox({ 
    parent: 'container-id',
    stage: 'container-id',
    scale: 0.09,
    blur: false,
    isText: false
});
```

**Edit:** I created a fiddle with some modifications to the plugin that shows how to get centering working, http://jsfiddle.net/wwBJt/

Comment: It seems that doing that directs the script to simply draw the elements in the upper-left corner as if to say that without xOffset and yOffset parameters, the plugin defaults to 0,0 coordinates.

Comment: Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/wwBJt/. I've added a function that calculates the center offset of the object relative to the parent container. I hope this gives you some inspiration of how to solve this. As a side note, the plugin is very poorly optimized, you should for example cache the DOM elements.

Comment: Thank you! This did just the trick and after studying it, it seems very logical. I was thinking there was some way to make the script accept percentage values when really it just needed to understand where the center was and base its positioning of elements off of that. As for the optimizing, I'll look into that stuff too since this plugin makes Firefox use far too much CPU.